# add hover/enter/leave capabilities to element in my QGraphicsScene

Tags: c++, qt, hover, point

basically I am trying to implement the Hover event on a QPointF, I need it to be clickable or at least being highlighted in some way.

What I've tried is to create a custom point starting by inheriting from QPointF, and then added hover,enter and leave methods as described in [this tutorial](http://amin-ahmadi.com/2016/02/01/mouse-hover-over-event-qt-widget/), but it is not working. Also, the tut is based on generic QWidget and not specifically on points.

have you guys some hints/resources? google points me on a few tuts that are not useful, and the Qt page referred to HoverEvent is not tailored with examples.

thanks!

**EDIT**

More info needed. I am trying to draw a rectangle in a scene. The rectangle is of type `QPolygonF` and the scene is a `QGraphicsScene` type.

below the code block used to create a polygon from a list of points and its inclusion in the scene:

```
void
MyDialog::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  Q_UNUSED(event);
  QPolygonF poly;
  QPointF first;

  for(int i = 0;i < points->size();i++)
  {
       double length = points->at(i).split(",").at(0).toDouble();
       double rad = qDegreesToRadians( points->at(i).split(",").at(1).toDouble());

       QPointF pt(length * qCos(rad),length * qSin(rad));
       if(i == 0) first = pt;

       poly << pt;
  }
    poly << first;


  scene->addPolygon(poly,QPen(),QBrush(Qt::green,Qt::SolidPattern));

}
```

Comment: QPointF is a simple data class, not a widget. How could you even hover over a data-class, it is not represented in a GUI in any way. You should elaborate why you want to do this, as there is propably a different class (or at least approach) you should use for your use case

Comment: @Felix sorry, you are right. I am a firmware developer, not used to work with OO and Qt, and I have no time to dig deeper. Actually, I was sure a QPoint was a graphical element put in a scene, but now I remember that a point is put into a scene in order to be "painted". Perhaps I'll have to think of working on the scene instead?

Comment: I think you want to work using `QWidget` as it's most basic UI object

Comment: Generally speaking, yes. You have to subclass or connect to whatever class actually represents the element to be drawn. This depends on how you draw the Scene. QWidgets, QML, QSceneGraph are some examples. Once we know which frontend is used we can find out how to archive it

Comment: @Felix I'll edit the post with more infos.

Comment: `QPointF` is a class representing an abstract concept - a pair of coordinates. It can't be visible, since this pair of coordinates has no concrete meaning. It's just two numbers, not much different than if you had `struct QPointF { qreal x, y; };`. To make it visible, you have to use the coordinates in some action that results in a visible entity. For example, you could use it to place a circle on the graphics scene, or draw a circle using `QPainter`.

Answer (score 1):

`QPointF` is a data object; it does not provide any graphical representation whatsoever (and I would strongly advise you against inheriting from it to add one).

One way to possibly do it is to override the `QGraphicsScene::mouseMoveEvent()` and `QGraphicsScene::mousePressEvent()` functions, allowing you to listen-in on where the user moves and clicks, and reacting on that. There are probably better ways to do this, though - I've only needed to react on clicks (and not on hovers) so far, so my experiences are limited.